# (await page).fill dosent work correctly in my case

Tags: javascript, async-await

The code below is supposed to fill in the password and Email fields, but in fact it fills in the Email field as "passmail@mail.ru". Please help.

````
(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 5000,
    devtools: true,
  });
  const page = browser.newPage();

  (await page).goto("url");

  (await page).click("text=Enter");

  (await page).fill('[type="password"]', "pass");

  (await page).fill('[placeholder="Email"]', "mail@mail.ru");

  (await page).click('button:has-text("OK")');

  (await page).click('button:has-text("log-in")');
})();```
````

Comment: It worked with 
```function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```
and by setting sleep after entering values in each field, but I would like to do without sleep

Comment: `await page.fill('[type="password"]', "pass");`